# Picking random integer not in a list between range

Tags: python, random

I need to randomly pick an integer between two integers but that integer can't be in a list.
This is how I am doing it:

```
bannedReturningCustomersIndex = []
index = next(iter(set(range(0, 999)) - set(bannedReturningCustomersIndex)))
#some code..
bannedReturningCustomersIndex.append(index)
```

The problem is that I'm not pickig the integer randomly, I'm picking them 1 by 1 from the beginning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `random.choice` after converting to a list:

```
import random
bannedReturningCustomersIndex = []
valid_indexes = list(set(range(0, 999)) - set(bannedReturningCustomersIndex))
bannedReturningCustomersIndex.append(random.choice(valid_indexes))
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the previous answer is correct, I'd like to propose the following approch, which is more readable, flexible and separates the logic from your main code.

```
import random

def iterRandNonBannedCustomers(banned_idx, c_idx=range(0, 999)):
    c_idx = list(c_idx)
    random.shuffle(c_idx)
    return filter(lambda i: i not in banned_idx, c_idx)
```

The function returns an iterator over all non-banned customers. Use it, for example, like this:

```
for customer in iterRandNonBannedCustomers(bannedReturningCustomersIndex):
    # do stuff
```